# After WordPress 4.3 update widget does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

After I updated the WordPress to 4.3 my widget does not work.
Before the update my widget was working just fine.
I walked through google but i found nothing that can help me except they say that I have to use the __construct function which I am using.
Any help ?

ps. I know I have included the file, the widget appears in widget list i also did drop the widget on the sidebar but it does not print "This is the content of widget" on the sidebar.

This is my simple code : (edit: below is the edited code and works now. Thanks to the two guys that offered the solution)

```
<?php

class test_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
  parent::__construct(
    'test_pop', // Base ID
    __( 'test widget', 'text_domain' ), // Name
    array( 'description' => __( 'A test Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
  );

  add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'widgets_init'));
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  echo $args['before_widget'];
  echo "<h1> This is the content of widget<h1>";
  echo $args['after_widget'];
}

public function form( $instance ) {

}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
  $instance = array();
  return $instance;
}

}

function test_widget_register() {
  register_widget( 'test_widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'test_widget_register' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside function `__construct`:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(
    //define your widgets ID,Name, Description.
    )
    add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'widgets_init'));
}
```

then apply user5251252 above of for function update.

Answer (score 3):

```
<pre><code>
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {        
        $instance = array();        
        return $instance;       
    }
</code></pre>
```

`$instance` must be set.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much, but it does not work with that either.

Answer (score 0):

These problem came from plugins. because some plugin old version  have class name and function name is same so you will do these,

1. First deactive all plugins and update all plugins.it will work.

Example:

```
    class PHP_Code_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function PHP_Code_Widget() {

   }
```